# How does this line in a single file of a node express app allow the variable to be accessed in other files?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a node app using Express and Mongoose.  I have seen this line in demo app but I don't understand how it is working.

### app.js

```
require('./db.js');
require('./routes.js')(app);
```

### db.js

```
exports = mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/test');
exports = Schema = mongoose.Schema;

require('./models.js')
```

### models.js

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
    title       : {type : String, default : '', trim : true}
  , body        : {type : String, default : '', trim : true}
  , user        : {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'}
  , created_at  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
})


mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
```

### routes.js

```
var Article = mongoose.model('Article');

module.exports = function(app){

    app.get('/new', function(req, res){
        var article = new Article({});
        res.render('new', article);     
    });
};
```

How are the variables mongoose and schema available in the other modules like models.js and routes.js?

This code all still works if I change the `exports = mongoose = require('mongoose');` line I saw in the demo to either of these which I am more familiar with.

```
module.exports = mongoose = require('mongoose');
exports.anything = mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

The variable name in the middle of the three assignments is what is available in other files.

Can someone explain what is going on here and how it is working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

**app.js**

```
var db = require('./db.js');
require('./routes.js')(app, db);
```

**db.js**

```
var mongoose;
module.exports.mongoose = mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/test');
module.exports.Schema = mongoose.Schema;

require('./models.js')(module.exports);
```

**models.js**

```
module.exports = function (db) {
    var ArticleSchema = new db.Schema({
        title       : {type : String, default : '', trim : true}
      , body        : {type : String, default : '', trim : true}
      , user        : {type : db.Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'}
      , created_at  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
    })

    db.mongoose.model('Article', ArticleSchema);
};
```

**routes.js**

```
module.exports = function (app, db) {
    var Article = db.mongoose.model('Article');

    app.get('/new', function(req, res){
        var article = new Article({});
        res.render('new', article);     
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Vadim, but the code I included worked already.  My question was why!  What you have done in your code is exactly how I had read and expected things to work but there is something about the line `exports = mongoose = require('mongoose')` that makes the `mongoose` variable available in other files.  I just can't see why!

Comment: Interestingly the line `module.exports = mongoose = require('mongoose')` and `exports.[any-name] = mongoose = require('mongoose')` have the same effect.

Comment: Sorry for not immediately understand your question. It's worked because you do not use var keyword. And variables mongoose and Schema defined as global. They will continue to work even if you remove exports keyword.

Comment: Definition of global variables is not best practice. In my example, all variables are local and are passed to other modules through the function calls.

Comment: Spot on!  I understand now.  Thank you.  I would up vote based on your comments but I don't have enough points to do that.